# Failed assertion: line 22 pos 14: 'url != null': is not true

Tags: flutter, listview, dart, null, flutter-layout

I want to show an image in a list view tile called ProfileTile from a network image and when it runs it gives me this error :

'package:flutter/src/painting/_network_image_io.dart': Failed assertion: line 22 pos 14: 'url != null': is not true.
The relevant error-causing widget was:
ProfileTile file:///Users/ahmed/AndroidStudioProjects/flutter_app_service2/lib/screens/home/profile_list.dart:28:16

I defined profile.dart as follows

```
return ListView.builder(
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return ProfileTile(profile: profiles[index]);
  },
```

The ProfileTile calss is like so :

```
class ProfileTile extends StatelessWidget {
final Profile profile;
ProfileTile({this.profile});

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Padding(
  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
  child: Card(
    margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 6.0, 20.0, 0.0),
    child: ListTile(
      leading: CircleAvatar(
        backgroundImage: NetworkImage(profile.imgUrl),
        radius: 25.0,

      ),
      title: Text(profile.firstName + ' ' + profile.lastName),
      subtitle: Text(profile.city + ' ' + profile.country),
    ),
  ),
);
```

}
}

the Database file as follows:

```
class DatabaseService {
final String uid;
DatabaseService({this.uid});

//collection reference
final CollectionReference profileCollection =
  Firestore.instance.collection('profiles');

Future updateUserData(String firstName, String lastName, String country,
  String city, String imgUrl) async {
return await profileCollection.document(uid).setData({
  'firstName': firstName,
  'lastName': lastName,
  'country': country,
  'city': city,
  'imgUrl': imgUrl,
});
}

//profile list from a snapshot
List<Profile> _profileListFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
return snapshot.documents.map((doc) {
  return Profile(
    firstName: doc.data['firstName'] ?? '',
    lastName: doc.data['lastName'] ?? '',
    country: doc.data['country'] ?? '',
    city: doc.data['city'] ?? '',
    imgUrl: doc.data['imgUrl'],
  );
}).toList();
}

//get profiles list
Stream<List<Profile>> get profiles {
return profileCollection.snapshots().map(_profileListFromSnapshot);
}
}
```

I put the default value in auth.dart file like so:

```
Future registerWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password) async {
try {
  AuthResult result = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: email, password: password);
  FirebaseUser user = result.user;

  //create new document for the user with uid
  await DatabaseService(uid: user.uid).updateUserData(
      'Ahmed', 'Hussein', 'Alexandria', 'Egypt', 'https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/BmvVMEzNQQ4rfIQXput2yOriDRc=/0x0:5568x3712/1820x1213/filters:focal(2858x720:3748x1610):format(webp)/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/62207705/922984782.jpg.0.jpg');
  return _userFromFirebaseUser(user);
} catch (e) {
  print(e.toString());
  return null;
}
}
```

Comment: this `profile.imgUrl` is null

Comment: Could you please tell me how to fix it? because it is 'final' and I can not set default value to it

Comment: you are giving it a value here `ProfileTile(profile: profiles[index])` u need to print it and check what it contains

Comment: here is the Profile class: 'class Profile {
  final String firstName;
  final String lastName;
  final String country;
  final String city;
  final String imgUrl;

  Profile(
      {this.firstName, this.lastName, this.country, this.city, this.imgUrl});
}'

Comment: I print it and it gave me 'Instance of Profile' for every index except imgUrl like so :[Instance of 'Profile', Instance of 'Profile', Instance of 'Profile', Instance of 'Profile']

Comment: Thanks @PeterHaddad. I found the problem after printing it that there were some documents in the collection without imgUrl field so I deleted them and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

check all your links to firebase and check the nodes there.
You probably misplaced something i.e.  my error was a null url when trying to fetch a product that did not exist - it was mistaking orders by products because of an error.
firebaseio.com/products.json';
firebaseio.com/orders.json';
I DID
firebaseio.com/PRODUCTS/orders.json';
this makes orders be products, but the orders do not have url..... thats the error.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem after printing

```
ProfileTile(profile: profiles[index])
```

there were some documents in the collection without imgUrl field so I deleted them and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to store Firebaseuser's photoUrl in a String named url. But the problem was that I was declaring it inside the build method.